# Authorized Request Origins is not restricting domain access in Firebase?

Tags: cross-domain, firebase, angularfire

I'm building an application using AngularFire + Firebase.
To prevent new users from being created, and authenticated, from domains other than my application's domain, I'm trying to use the `Authorized Request Origins` feature in Firebase.

Currently, it is only configured to allow authentication from `localhost`. However, when I create a new user using the `createUser` API from my application's domain, the user gets created in my Firebase.
This should not happen since I used `"err" from createUser is null`.

Is there anything else I need to configure?

Answer (score 1):

[Engineer at Firebase] The authorized request origins is actually only applicable to the OAuth-based authentication providers (i.e. Facebook, Twitter, and GitHub) though your confusion is definitely warranted given our current interface. E-mail and password authentication is not subject to the same origin verification because it is not vulnerable to a malicious site taking advantage of an existing login on Facebook, Twitter, etc.

Keep it mind that email / password authentication only creates a mapping of an email address to a password hash, and generates a corresponding Firebase authentication token upon login. It does not read or write any data to / from your Firebase, and your Firebase is still subject to the same security rules that you've written for your application. Feel free to reach out to support@firebase.com if you have other concerns, or we can help out in any way.