# How to set up IP/domain-wise security rules in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

"Authentication requests to Firebase Simple Login are only permitted from domains you specify." and the two default domains are "localhost" and "127.0.0.1".

Let's say that my server's IP is "267.156.423.22". How do I setup my security rules so that that the two first domains can read specific data, but only the server can write it?

For example, if a client purchases a product, this fact and associated data needs to be noted on the client's account in the Firebase. For obvious security reasons this information must be 'writeable' by the server only.

Comment: This question and ["Authorized Request Origins is not restricting domain access in Firebase?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19058176/331508) appear to be essentially duplicates of each other.

Answer (score 3):

The authorized domains configuration for Firebase Simple Login applies solely to OAuth-based authentication providers (Facebook, Twitter, and GitHub), and restricts requests to those origins in the browser.

That means if you're using one of those OAuth-based authentication providers, you'd want to enter in any origins which your end users will use to access the page (i.e. if your user accesses the page via subdomain.example.com, that'd the be origin to enter).

Keep in mind that Firebase Simple Login is built on top of that standard, one-size-fits-all custom login / token generation in Firebase. It is an abstraction layer intended to make it easy to generate Firebase Auth. Tokens, a secure way of sharing data between you and Firebase.

Once a token has been generated (via Simple or Custom login), you can begin using that token's payload in your security rules (via the `auth` variable). If you'd want your server to bypass security rules, simple generate a token with the `admin` privilege, or your Firebase secret. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/security-rules.html for more details.